# Check string for only numbers using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

My question is: is there any way to check using jstl if given a string that string contains only numbers ?

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to implicitly cast a string to a number and catch any exception (if there is one) using `c:catch`. For example:

```
<c:catch var="catchString">
  <c:set var="myString" value="${0 + 'asd1234'}" />
</c:catch>
<c:if test="${not empty catchString}">
  <p>Failed: ${catchString}</p>
</c:if>

<c:catch var="catchNumber">
  <c:set var="myNumber" value="${0 + '1234'}" />
</c:catch>
<c:if test="${not empty catchNumber}">
  <p>Failed: ${catchNumber}</p>
</c:if>
```

Will output this:

```
<p>Failed: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asd1234"</p>
```

If you want to prevent floats you could build a check using `fmt:formatNumber` to check for decimals:

```
<c:set var="myFloat" value="12"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${myFloat}" pattern="0" var="myInteger"/>
<c:if test="${myInteger - myFloat eq 0}">
  <p>No decimals</p>
</c:if>
```

Of course you could combine this with the `c:catch` to catch number format exceptions.

```
<c:set var="myString" value="abc12.34"/>
<c:catch>
  <fmt:formatNumber value="${myString}" pattern="0" var="myInteger"/>
  <c:set var="passed" value="${myInteger - myString eq 0}"/>
</c:catch>

<c:if test="${passed}">
  <p>Passed</p>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${not passed}">
  <p>Failed</p>
</c:if>
```