# JSP, JSTL, Check NaN

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a JSP in which I am using `<fmt:formatNumber>`. The problem is that we don't know that the value coming to JSP will be a number or a String. If a string is coming it throws NumberFormatException.

I tried to look in JSTL, but no success, somewhere it was mentioned if I check value == value it returns false if String but no success. Please see the code below.

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" >${primary.value}</fmt:formatNumber>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you included more code so that the problem can be seen in context.  Also, why do you not have control over what the value is?

Comment: The value is coming from different vendor which is why we don't have any control

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482062/check-string-for-only-numbers-using-jstl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a solution to your problem. You'll get an exception when you try to add a String to 0.

```
<c:catch var="catchString">
  <c:set value="${0 + primary.value}" />
</c:catch>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${not empty catchString}">
  ${primary.value}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
  <fmt:formatNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" >${primary.value}</fmt:formatNumber>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: It worked...but do we have any other solution..I am asking so coz we have around 30 such fields..If you can suggest any JSTL or anything like that,then number of code lines would be less.

Comment: Can you not put those fields in a loop?
You could use a ternary to get rid of the c:choose-tag.

Comment: I am using below mentioned less code      `<c:catch var="catchString">
       <fmt:formatNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" >${primary.value}</fmt:formatNumber>
     </c:catch>
     <c:if test="${not empty catchString}">
       ${primary.value}
     </c:if>`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a custom tag library to check wether you're dealing with a String or with a number, or even to manually format your number (your choice).

I don't have time to work out the example for you but I found this 
[Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31614/JSP-JSTL-Custom-Tag-Library)
where they explain step by step on how to implement everything.

**Edit:** More info @[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio)

I hope you get it to work, if not let me know and I'll try to help you out tomorrow.